# Select class constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make class template constructor `default` if it is trivial and default for `T`, something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class my_class {
public:
    template <typename <std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
    constexpr my_class() = default;

    template <typename <std::enable_if<!std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
    constexpr my_class() {};
}
```

Of course, this code does not work (empty parameter if condition does not met). How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide separate specializations for when `T` is and is not trivially default-constructible:

```
template <typename T, bool = std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>::value>
class my_class {
public:
    constexpr my_class() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class my_class<T, false> {
public:
    constexpr my_class() {};  
};
```

Comment: Imagine that `my_class` is a very big class (100+ methods), this way do I need to copy all of them to both specializations?

Comment: @vladon yes, you would. Are you sure you need this anyway? Is an object of type `T` stored in `my_class`? Are you trying to make `my_class` trivially constructible only if `T` is?

Comment: Yes, I store object of type `T` in `my_class`, and yes, I want to make it trivially default constructible if T is trivially default constructible.

Comment: @vladon Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you get that for free? If a class has a member variable which isn't trivially-constructible, then that class isn't trivially-constructible either. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3062e54c075b4688)

Comment: Ok, but I want constructor to be `= default` when it is possible.